# Casting anonymous type to dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, anonymous-types

I have a function that returns an anonymous type which I want to test in my MVC controller.

```
public JsonResult Foo()
{
    var data = new
                  {
                      details = "something",
                      more = "More"
                  };
    return Json(data);
}
```

I want to verify the data I get from the Foo function, What I'm doing now is getting the data type and get it's properties values with reflection.

```
[Test]
public void TestOne()
{
    var data = _controller.Foo().Data;
    var details = data.GetType().GetProperty("details").GetValue(data, null);
    var more = data.GetType().GetProperty("more").GetValue(data, null);

    Assert.AreEquals("something", details);
    Assert.AreEquals("More", more);
}
```

Is there a simple way similar to this to check the anonymous properties?

```
[Test]
public void TestTwo()
{
    var data = (dynamic) _controller.Foo().Data;
    var details = data.details; // RunTimeBinderException object does not contain definition for details
    var more = data.more;

    Assert.AreEquals("something", details);
    Assert.AreEquals("More", more);
}
```

Comment: Since this is for unit testing, you could use `InternalsVisibleTo`. See [Anonymous Types are Internal, C# 4.0 Dynamic Beware!](http://www.heartysoft.com/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic) Thanks to @MarcGravell for pointing out that anonymous objects are `internal`!

Comment: +1 for InternalsVisibleTo suggestion. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Anonymous objects are `internal`, which means their members are very restricted outside of the assembly that declares them. `dynamic` respects accessibility, so pretends not to be able to see those members. If the call-site was in the same assembly, I expect it would work.

Your reflection code respects the *member* accessibility, but bypasses the type's accessibility - hence it works.

In short: no.

Comment: @gdoron why would it? It is still an object, after all. It just doesn't expose much else. ToString(), Equals(), GetHashCode(), etc will still all work via dynamic. It just doesn't add anything else visible.

Comment: Longer answer: _maybe_ yes, if you can use `InternalsVisibleTo`. See my answer further down in this thread.

Answer (score 29):

This blog had a working answer: http://blog.jorgef.net/2011/06/converting-any-object-to-dynamic.html - Thanks @Jorge-Fioranelli.

```
public static class DynamicExtensions {
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object value) {
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType()))
            expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(value));

        return expando as ExpandoObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: this was useful to a little coding exercise I was doing, but it should be modified to handle properties that are also anonymous. `bool isNotPrimitiveOrString = !(property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || Equals(property.PropertyType, typeof(string))); expando.Add(property.Name, (isNotPrimitiveOrString) ? property.GetValue(value).ToDynamic() : property.GetValue(value));`

Comment: also, it seems you cannot use this as an extension to Anonymous Objects, must be `DynamicExtensions.ToDynamic(data)` call/usage.

Comment: note: the above snippet for nest anonymous doesn't seem to work for `PropertInfo` class, but does for `PropertyDescriptor` (like in the code sample).  Interesting.

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by @TrueWill and @Marc Gravell, who also referred to [this blog post](http://www.heartysoft.com/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic)

*Since this is for unit testing, you could use InternalsVisibleTo. See Anonymous Types are Internal, C# 4.0 Dynamic Beware! Thanks to @MarcGravell for pointing out that anonymous objects are internal!*

Bottom line: Set up an `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("foo")]` mapping if you want to share an anonymous object from one assembly to another. In the OP case, it would be a matter of setting this in the MVC controller project, referring to the *test project*. In my specific case, the other way around (since I'm passing an anonymous object from my test project into the "production code" project).

The easiest way in that "other project" to be able to use it is definitely to cast it to `dynamic` and then just use the properties like normal. It does work, no problems whatsoever.

So, bottom line: I feel that Marc Gravell's answer is slightly incorrect; this can clearly be done
(*iff* the projects in question are modifiable by you, so you can set up the InternalsVisibleTo mapping accordingly, and this does not pose a problem for whatever other reason).

Answer (score 9):

Anonymous type is a regular static type in .NET, it's just that you do not give it a name (a compiler, however, does). That's why casting it to `dynamic` will not work. However, if you have control over `Foo()`, you can construct and return a `dynamic` object instead of anonymous, and then your code is going to work. This should do the trick:

```
dynamic JsonResult Foo() {
    dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
    data.details = "something";
    data.mode = "More";
    return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: .Data is "object". There's little difference between "object" and "dynamic", except at the consumer (which is where it gets fun). I do not believe that changing between "object" and "dynamic" (and then back to dynamic) will do much here.

Comment: @MarcGravell I added code to clarify what I mean by *returning dynamic* (I actually meant "construct a dynamic object and return it," not simply "change the return type to dynamic"). Thanks for catching it - the initial edit indeed was not clear.

Comment: The main thing that makes this work is: ExpandoObject is public not internal (and of course implements the IDynamicBlahBlahBlah interface as a public claim). However, it prompts the important question: does the JSON layer like ExpandoObject? (it *might* due to the IDictionary usage). It also means we are no longer using an anon type (question)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NewtonSoft or the Asp.net MVC libraries:

`var data = Json.Decode(Json.Encode(_controller.Foo().Data));`

`var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject((_controller.Foo().Data))`