# Why anonymous types have internal visibility in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Is this because of security issues that could happen if anonymous types were public? I just don't get.

That's the kind of code I wanted to be supported by the language

Assembly 1

```
public class Renderer
{
    public void RenderHtmlInput(dynamic inputModel)
    {
        var html = string.format("<input type='text' width='{0}' height='{1}'>", inputModel.width, inputModel.height);
        ...
    }
}
```

Assembly 2

```
public class Consumer
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var renderer = new Renderer();

        renderer.RenderInput(new { width = "12px", height = "20px" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Google, this is a classic question.

Comment: http://www.heartysoft.com/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic

Comment: They are anonymous, meaning they have no name you can refer to. How would you refer to an anonymous type externally?

Comment: @Oded. `dynamic`... Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465121/casting-anonymous-type-to-dynamic)

Comment: @gdoron - Anonymous types were introduced before `dynamic` was available.

Comment: @Oded. You asked... **:-)** anyway I believe the DLR- dynamic was planned to come when anonymous introduced.

Comment: @gdoron - Yes, but it wasn't available and it was not possible to expose anonymous types at the time. Changing the visibility rules of anonymous types would be a breaking change.

Comment: @Oded I don't see how this could be a breaking change.

Comment: ken2k's link has a new URL: http://heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/05/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're supposed to use them in the same library.
It's not ok to expose anonymous types over interfaces or class boundaries.

If you want to do that, use dynamic types.

**Edit:** Anonymous types also have their names automatically generated, so exposing them from a library means they can conflict with anonymous types from another library.

Comment: Actually, `dynamic` can *also* obey accessibility rules, especially when it is `dynamic` against a type using reflection

Comment: @linkerro why "It's not ok to expose anonymous types over interfaces or class boundaries"?

Comment: @linkerro Why am I supposed to use them in the same library? I don´t see how this could be a security issue. Anonymous types are just classes with a bunch of properties having only getters. How can this be harmful?

Comment: It's not a security issue, it's a "usability" issue. If you want to declare a variable that takes an anonymous class you can't do it unless it's right next to the code that generates that class. The compiler cannot infer the type of a variable otherwise. Also you can't unbox anonymous types.

Comment: I don't want to declare a variable of anonymous type but it would be nice to have in one assembly a method taking a dynamic parameter and be able to pass a anonymous type to this method from another assembly.