# Has dynamic changed in .net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I'm writing a unit test to test the results of calling a controller method. I know for a fact that it will return an anonymous object with a single property "error" in the case of a bad parameter.

```cs
[Test]
public async Task should_inform_about_invalid_param()
{
    var res = await Controller.Index("Donkey");
    Assert.That(res, Is.Typeof<BadRequestObjectResult>());
    var obj = (res as BadRequestObjectResult).Value;
    dynamic dyn = obj; 
    string errorText = dyn.error;
    Assert.That(errorText, Contains.Substring("Donkey"));
}
```

The actual test does not matter. However, I would expect this to work and be able get out the result. Instead I get the following exception

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'error'

Now I can use reflection to extract the error, however it is ugly and cumbersome.

```
var errorText = obj.GetType().GetProperty("error").GetValue(obj) as string
```

has this changed? I felt in the past I could always use `dynamic` to extract the value of dynamic objects.

Edit: 
Attached a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: The error message is correct: `object` doesn't contain an `error` property or method.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using two steps to extract `Value` from your `BadRequestObjectResult` instead of one?  `dynamic dyn = (res as BadRequestObjectResult).Value;`

Comment: There's no real reason, just how the test was written. Maybe it made it easier to debug. Yes, object does contain error, but dynamic should be able to find that there is an `error` property on the the anonymous object that is stored in the object.

Comment: Try it in one step.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that is erroring, hover the mouse over that dynamic variable in the debugger, and let's see what its actual type is.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: It appears that  anonymous types are considered `internal` to the assembly in which they are declared.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8465121

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the issue is related to the fact that anonymous types are internal to the declaring assembly.

A solution is to mark the hosting assembly with an `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo(UnitTestLibraryName)]`
Doing this allows dynamic to visit the members of the anonymous type.